# Copy data in columns from 1 workbook to another

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I would like to use Excel vba to copy data from a particular column from one workbook to another. For example, I would like to copy column A, B, E, G, H, M, N in workbook 1 to workbook 2, starting from A2.

Currently, I am using this example but it doesn't serve the purpose that I want the macro to act. I had included the codes that I am currently using as per below:

```
Sub SO()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm").WorkSheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsm").WorkSheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy

ws2.Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an explanation and an example:

You use

```
 ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy
                    ^                  ^
                    |                  |
                    Column 1           Column 1
```

So this copies the range from column 1 to column 1 between row 2 and the last row.

If you change it to

```
 ws1.Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(lastRow, "C")).Copy
```

It will copy the range of the columns A to D (A, B, C and D) between row 2 and the last row.

If you don't need column B in the example above then you will need to copy and paste column A and columns C+D independently in 2 copy/paste actions.